# Dynamically pass URL to window media control in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net

HERE is the code i am using to set wm control

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfNameOfFile" Value='0' runat="server" />
                            <div id="mediaPlayerDiv">
                                <object id="mediaPlayer1" classid="CLSID:22d6f312-b0f6-11d0-94ab-0080c74c7e95" width="350"
                                    height="70" standby="Loading Microsoft Windows Media Player components..." type="application/x-oleobject">
                                    <param name="fileName" value="0">
                                    <param name="animationatStart" value="true">
                                    <param name="transparentatStart" value="true">
                                    <param name="loop" value="false">
                                    <param name="ShowDisplay" value="false">
                                    <param name="ShowStatusBar" value="true">
                                    <param name="volume" value="200" />
                                </object>
                            </div>
```

I have a code already made whose java script does something i do not understand below is java script .

```
 function pageLoad() {
                try {



                    document.getElementById('mediaPlayerDiv').innerHTML = '<object id="mediaPlayer1" classid="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6" width="350" '
                                                                            + ' height="70" standby="Loading Microsoft Windows Media Player components..." type="application/x-oleobject" >'
                                                                            + '<param name="URL" value="' + $('#<%=hfNameOfFile.ClientID %>').val() + '" />'
                                                                            + '<param name="animationatStart" value="true" /> '
                                                                            + '<param name="transparentatStart" value="true" /> '
                                                                            + '<param name="loop" value="false" /> '
                                                                            + '<param name="autoStart" value="True" /> '
                                                                            + '<param name="ShowDisplay" value="false" /> '
                                                                            + '<param name="ShowStatusBar" value="true" /> '
                                                                            + '<param name="volume" value="50" /> '
                                                                            + '<param name="uimode" value="full" /> '
                                                                            + ' </object> ';

                    document.getElementById('mediaPlayer1').controls.stop();
```

I have two main questions , i do not understand what this javascript is doing specially the part where value of url is set . and second question is that how shall i send url value dynamically to the control in div from code behind .

Comment: Is the page refreshing where you want to update the url?

Comment: I have a grid view with clickable columns and those columns have name and path of audio files . I want that the value for column clicked is somehow passed to window media player controller .

Comment: So this is client-side - meaning you don't refresh the page with the new URL?

Comment: Window media control is not necessary i used this code to succesfuly play audio files     

System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"c:\9104.wav");
       player.Play();
But the problem is once the file starts playing it does not stop untill it finishes even if i refresh whole page . if i can somehow stop and start it on desire i would leave media player control at side as it does not fit on my page nicely

Comment: Yes client side . by url i mean path of audio file  , MY audio file and project is hosted on same network .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the way to do it myself

```
 <object id="mediaPlayer1" classid="CLSID:22d6f312-b0f6-11d0-94ab-0080c74c7e95" width="350"
                                height="70" standby="Loading Microsoft Windows Media Player components..." type="appli
  ...
<param name="filename" VALUE='<%= MyURL %>'>
 ...
 </object>
```

and then in code behind i did

```
 MyUrl = "http://foo/foo.mpg";
```